# Using env variables to set other variables in Jenkins pipeline as code

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I cannot use environment variables set in previous blocks in access stage below.

```
pipeline{
agent any
stages{

      stage("set env variable"){

      steps{
           script{
             env.city = "Houston"
             }
          }
       } 
     }
     stage("access"){
     steps{
           sh """
              set brf = ${env.city}
              echo $brf

              """

         }

     }



  } 
  }
```

> ERROR: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: brf for class: groovy.lang.Binding

What is an easier way to use jenkins declarative pipeline env variables ?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

> I cannot use environment variables set in previous blocks in access stage below.

If you look closely at the error, you can see Jenkins is actually unable to access `brf`, not `env.city`.

The issue here is caused by the way Jenkins interprets `$var` inside `sh` block:

- if you use `"double quotes"`, `$var` in `sh "... $var ..."` will be interpreted as Jenkins variable;
- if you use `'single quotes'`, `$var` in `sh '... $var ...'` will be interpreted as shell variable.

Since the `sh` code in your script is wrapped in `"double quotes"`, `$brf` is considered to be a Jenkins variable, while there is no such variable defined, therefore the error occurs.

To use shell variable inside double-quoted block add `\` before `$`:

```
sh "echo \$var"
```

works the same way as

```
sh 'echo $var'
```

This should fix your pipeline script:

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage("set env variable"){
            steps{
                script{
                    env.city = "Houston"
                }
            }
        }
        stage("access"){
            steps{
                sh """
                    brf=${env.city}
                    echo \$brf
                """
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output from the pipeline:

```
[test] Running shell script
+ brf=Houston
+ echo Houston
Houston
```

Comment: If setting the variable in pipeline {  environment { city="Houston .., both sh 'echo $city' and sh "echo $city" does work (Jenkins 2.150)

Comment: The amazing explanation when mixing shell and groovy variables in Jenkins. This saved my day. thanks.

Comment: Can we access the variable brf outside of the shell if we use sh """ code """ ?
I tried doing the same thing, it works as expected but only when I try to access that variable from different stage it could not find it, even if I set it as a env variable. Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: thank you for this explanation on the quotes and double quotes... very very important

Comment: @honorius very simple question what about if we want to access the jenkins variable inside the single quote is there a way to also escape that?

Comment: @honorius God bless you for your answer

Comment: This is not how it's documented to work. Env variables set in one stage are not supposed to be accessible in subsequent stages. For example: "The directive can also be placed in the stages. Thus, that variable can be used only in steps of that particular stage." - https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/set-jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-list/  This is extremely confusing. I confirmed in Jenkins 2.306 that the env set in one stage is _not_ in fact visible in later stages.

Answer (score -3):

You should not have any problem to get the variables with this code:

```
 stage("access"){
     steps{
           sh "set brf = ${env.city}"
           echo '$brf'

      //or 
      sh "set brf = ${env.city} && echo $brf"

      }
 }
```

I think this is what you had asked but let me know if you have another doubt.

Comment: This appears to be `csh` (C shell) code rather than the more standard `sh` (Bourne shell / dash) or `bash`.  I don't think first part of your example would work, since  the`brf` variable is set in the shell process and Jenkins' built-in `echo` doesn't have access to that variable.